# How replicate GIT code from bitbucket to github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

We need to replicate any change in a repository in BitBucket to a repository in GitHub. Which is the best option to track all the branches?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, the best way to do that is using BitBucket-pipelines.

So, steps are:

1. on github, create the new repository.
2. on bitbucket, generate a new SSH key under repository's `Settings / SSH keys` and copy the public part.
3. on github repository settings, add the public ssh key as a deployment key, with write permission.
4. now in your working copy you need to create the file `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` with this content (remember to replace the git repository url):

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          # bitbucket options will fetch just the current branch, so it is required to fetch all:
          - git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
          # fetch all branches:
          - git fetch --all
          # track all branches but HEAD and the current one, which is already being tracked:
          - for i in $(git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v "HEAD" | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"); do git branch --track ${i#remotes/origin/} $i; done
          # publish the current working copy to gtithub
          - git push --mirror <GIT REPOSITORY URL HERE>
```

Now, if you desire to do the opposite, to replicate from GitHub to BitBucket, probably it is easy to create a github-action which performs exactly the same steps!